# ChartJS 2 tooltip title is undefined

Tags: chartjs-2.6.0

I am looking to add the word "Ages " to my tooltip title, to represent age groups as per in the chart.

Basically, title should be "Ages 11-20", for example. However, I get "Ages undefined"?

Anyone know why I am getting this issue?

Code (fiddle below):

```
var ageRangedata = {type: 'bar',
data:{datasets: [
{ data : [0,1,5,2,1,0,0, 0, 0, 0], backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 209, 240, 0.6)', borderColor: 'rgba(255, 209, 240, 1)', borderWidth: 2, label: 'Female' },
{ data : [1,0,1,1,6,1,0, 1, 0, 0], backgroundColor: 'rgba(81, 187, 245, 0.6)', borderColor: 'rgba(81, 187, 245, 1)', borderWidth: 2, label: 'Male' }],

labels:['0-10','11-20','21-30','31-40','41-50','51-60','61-70', '71-80', '81-90', '90-']},
options: {maintainAspectRatio: false,responsive: true, tooltips: { callbacks: { title: function(tooltipItem, data) { return 'Ages ' + data.labels[tooltipItem.Index]; }}},legend: { display: false }}};

var ageR = document.getElementById("ageRange").getContext("2d");
var chart_ageR = new Chart(ageR, ageRangedata);
```

Extra points (side question, ignore if you want) to anyone who know what using afterLabel sends the text to just below the label instead of after it (as it sounds like it should be doing)"?

https://jsfiddle.net/unc76c7s/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
return 'Ages ' + tooltipItem[0].xLabel;
```

In any case your error is quite explicit. You could do a console.log of your tooltipItem in your callback to see if you're using it correctly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!